# How to detect a record is locked?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

With SQL Server 2008, how can I detect if a record is locked?

EDIT:

I need to know this, so I can notify the user that the record is not accessible because the record is blocked.

Comment: Could you explain further what you are asking? As in, why do you need to know if a record is locked?

Comment: I think you might be approaching this problem the wrong way: eliminate the locking rather than concentrating on reporting it to users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most circumstances with SQL 2008 you can do something like:

```
if exists(select 0 from table with (nolock) where id = @id) 
   and not exists(select 0 from table with(readpast) where id = @id)
begin
  -- Record is locked! Do something.

end
```

If that is not enough (that is, you need to ignore table-level locks as well), use the [`NOWAIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint that throws an error if there's a lock.

Comment: Thank you so much. What I needed was the NOWAIT hint!

Comment: voted for the `NOWAIT` THANK YOU